# XCTest how to toggle Notification Switch in OS Settings?

Tags: push-notification, toggle, settings, xctest, xcuitest

I'm trying to Enable / Disable the OS Notification Switch for the app I'm testing and I'm unable to.  I get as far as the Settings > Notifications > App screen itself but the switch doesn't seem to have a button I can interact with.

This is how far I get:

```
let settingsApp = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.Preferences")
        settingsApp.launch()
        
settingsApp.tables.cells.staticTexts["Notifications"].tap()
settingsApp.tables.cells.staticTexts["app_name"].tap()
```

So far so good but here the button list is returned like this:

```
Failed to get matching snapshot: No matches found for Element at index 7 from input {(
    Button,
    Button, identifier: 'Lock Screen', Selected,
    Button, identifier: 'Notification Center',
    Button, identifier: 'Banners',
    Button, Disabled,
    Button, Disabled
)}
```

I've tried `settingsApp.buttons.element(boundBy: 0).tap()` but that ends up being the back button and boundBy: 1 ends up being the 'Lock Screen' button.

Is the 'Allow Notifications' toggle un-tappable? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Allow Notifications** is a `switch`, which will respond to `tap()`. The following should do the trick:

```
settingsApp.tables.cells.switches["Allow Notifications"].tap()
```

I typically wrap switch tapping in a toggle function, which takes an expected state and only taps if it's not already in that state.